# "Portable" JAX-WS client

Tags: dynamic, wsdl, jax-ws, endpoints, wsimport

I deployed a JAX-WS Service and use wsimport to generate client code.
Because I run wsimport on localhost, I got the client code with binind on "localhost" address.

But I want to reuse those client code on other computers which access my deployed service with a public IP y.y.y.y. How can dynamically use those (once) generated client code to access my service. (The ip of service may change...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is covered in the [FAQ](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.10/docs/ch05.html#section-jaxws-faq6) of JAX-WS:

> **Q. How can I change the Web Service address dynamically for a request ?**
>
> ```
> ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "...");
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Take a look at the [JBoss example](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossWS-JAX-WSTools#TopDown_Using_wsconsume). Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://your.wsdl.location");
```

Usually the WSDL is generated and therfore the WS provider inserts the relevant URLs into the WSDL.